# Outlook undeliverable 501 error

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, ssl, imap

I have a really weird problem in Outlook 2016 and I can't put my finger on it.

In Outlook 2016 I have an e-mail account that until recently worked perfectly. The account is configured to use SSL for both IMAP and SMTP. I'm able to receive messages but am unable to send a message to any given e-mail address.

When I create a new e-mail and send it away I immediately get a server error 501 undeliverable error. If I use an non encrypted connection everything is fine. I can send messages and receive.

I've tried to remove the e-mail account, tried to repair the database (ost file) using the scan program in office, I've tried to reinstall Office entirely but nothing seems to solve the issue.

When I test the settings with SSL I do get the outlook test message in the inbox.

It must be something within Outlook because other clients like a mobile device works and a non encrypted connection works.

I hope someone is able to help me with this because I have no idea